# how to binarize an image?

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I don't want to binarize a certain image through another program, I want to know how to binarize things myself. All I know is that there is something to do with a threshold and if it is above the threshold it is either 1 or 0 and the opposite if below. My images are using RGB but I can also use HSB or HSV. I just want the algorithm to do so . :)

Comment: What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what research you've done.  This topic is described on Wikipedia, and a simple search on 'image binarization' turns up some references in the first result (even searching for just 'binarization' turns up some stuff among the first 10 hits).  As a rough rule of thumb, if your question can be answered using information readily findable on Wikipedia or in standard textbooks, you probably haven't done enough research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Otsu method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) to use variance when splitting.

Taking your own steps you should convert RGB to grayscale (simple mean like $(R+G+B)/3$, or use [luminance grayscale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)).

The next step is to give some threshold, from Otsu or arbitrary given by your choice, and operating on grayscale image everything below (or equal) is 0, so it will be black, and greater than threshold is 1 (white).

Operations on other scheme like HSL is exactly taking luminance, but the full change RGB -> HSL is not needed because you discard color info.

Situation when values are out of range does not occur, so do not worry.

Comment: How do i turn the image into a histogram

Comment: If you have 256 gray levels, you start from declaring that big array initialized with 0, and then for each pixel you increment proper bin (grayscale value, rounded).

Comment: Is it the number of accurances for each number between 0 and 256?

Comment: Yes, with minor change - 0 to 255 inclusively for 8bit colors.

Comment: I looked at the website you said to use for the otsu method and converted it to python but it dosn't seem to be giving me the right thresholds. Would it be ok to add that to my question or should I ask it on stack overflow?

Comment: The code here is not good place, but describing what happens is ok. Maybe some scaling issues or colors are differently stored? There are several steps, you should check separately color to grayscale conversion and binarization. 1 and 0 should be 255 and 0 if you still use 8bit after conversion, moreover apply it to all channels (RGB)